# How to properly change SSH ports in Microsoft Azure?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, azure

I have a virtual machine on Azure—for testing, not a production server—based on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The default SSH port `22` is opened by default.

I want to change it to `12131`. I  edited my SSH configuration file and changed port to `12131`, then reloaded ssh service by:

```
service ssh reload
```

Then I logged into my Windows Azure portal and updated endpoint SSH as:

- **Public Port** 12131
- **Private Port** 12131

Now I’m getting timeout with SSH. What is the proper way to change the default SSH port on Ubuntu 14.04 in Azure?

Answer (score 1):

I assuming you want to do it for security reasons.

You can just change the public port in Azure to something else and leave the ssh config in Ubuntu alone.

Go to the Azure dashboard, choose Virtual Machines, open your VM, go to endpoints, change the public port for SSH to 12131

Now when you try to ssh to it you will use port 12131 but it translates that to the internal port 22 set on the server, and port 22 externally goes nowhere.